# a problem with creating a site in IIS 7.5 which is using PHP

Tags: php, windows, iis

I am trying to run web application scripted in PHP on windows server 2008. I have configured PHP (as fastcgi) and IIS. Everything goes fine except the following scenario.

In the php.ini document "doc_root" edited with the correct root path for my php projects which is "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\". I created a new site on IIS and mapped it's path to "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\application1". When I try to open this site, I see that somehow (IIS or PHP no idea ) does nt run my new application on the path "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\application1". It tries to run on "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\", which returns 404 of course. What am I missing here ?

Comment: Silly question maybe but have you restarted the "world wide web" service so that your new php.ini change kicks in?

Comment: yep i did restarted. one of my friend recommended me to leave "doc_root" property blank. i will try that when i get back to my pc.

Comment: Have you checked this manual page: [Case 3: setting doc_root or user_dir](http://php.net/manual/en/security.cgi-bin.doc-root.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who have the same problem;

I have figured out the problem. setting "doc_root" is not right. As I commented that property in php.ini file it got ok.

Also checking the following url was helpful:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/246/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis-7/

Its written there that you can make your php web sites use seperate php.ini files. I found this link really usefull.

Don t want to choose my answer as the right one but have to. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see whether you are changing and  loading Correct php.ini file  using phpinfo()

Comment: i have figured out the problem. setting "doc_root" is not right. As I commented that property in php.ini file it got ok.